# Make github commit messages mandatory

Tags: github

Is there way i can make commit messages mandatory? I need this validation both from UI and API level so i dont see any commits that have blank description.

Is that possible?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Github Enterprise has this feature available [as a pre-receive hook](https://github.com/github/platform-samples/tree/master/pre-receive-hooks).

Examples of pre-receive hooks from the readme:

- **Require commit messages to follow a specific pattern or format, such
  as including a valid ticket number or being over a certain length.**
- Prevent sensitive data from being added to the repository by blocking keywords, patterns or filetypes.
- Prevent a PR author from merging their own changes.
- Prevent a developer from pushing commits of a different author or committer.
- Prevent a developer from pushing unsigned commits.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is possible. The UI always sets a default commit message if you do not specify one on your own. The extended description section, however, is optional and is probably specific to GitHub.